# How can a string be printed if there is nothing calling it? In cases using the return value of printf or scanf

Tags: c, printf

In the following code, how is the value of `st` printed along with the count of the numbers of characters in the string? Is the character string in printf printed before the string value ", the value returned ..." is printed?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{ 
  char st[] = "CODING"; 

  printf("While printing "); 
  printf(", the value returned by printf() is : %d", 
          printf("%s", st));
  int out = printf("%s", "hello");

  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: The internal `printf` is executed, then it's return value is passed to the outer`printf`. What's the mystery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the second `printf` statement is called, its arguments must first be evaluated.  One of those arguments is another call to `printf`.  So the inner `printf` is called first, printing "CODING", and that call returns the number of characters printed.

That value is then passed to the outer `printf` statement to print that value.